# Would GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.4 work with Eclipse Mars 4.5

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Just wanted to check if it would be a good idea to install GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.4 on Eclipse Mars 4.5. Also, if there are any plans for 4.5 plugin?

Comment: Sorry about that. Was looking for GWT plugin information. Found that GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.4 works fine on Eclipse 4.5

Comment: we should all star the "Support for Eclipse 4.5" thread: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=334

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you wait for the 4.5 plugin before upgrading eclipse. We waited quite a while for the 4.4 plugin, but it came.
I've tried 4.4 plugin in Mars, and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for responding Davorin. I am using the GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.4 on Eclipse 4.5 and it has been working fine now for over a month.

Comment: There is gwt plugin 4.5 available for use now.
Check this: Click [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.5 )!

Answer (score 2):

I'm having problems showing error messages in eclipse Mars (didn't have problems in Luna).

So I will say that NO. The plugin doesn't work well in Eclipse MARS.

Comment: Hi Mariano. I am using it on Mac and is working fine. Could you please give some details about the error message that you are getting? Also, could you confirm which OS you are on?  I had to modify the build path after moving my projects to Mars and that resolved a lot of errors.

Comment: I'm having this problem:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/comment/Java2HTMLEntityReader

When trying to see errores in debug mode.

No fix yet, and is very annoying:

https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/70

Answer (score 0):

I got GWT plugin version 4.4 to work in Mars **only with Eclipse Mars not installed from Eclipse Installer *('download Eclipse package' instead)***.

[image]

Using the installer resulted instead in the plugin then installing, but not appearing via blue GWT toolbar icon, Eclipse Google preferences, nor Eclipse project Google context menu.